# O que preciso pra vender um sistema em C#

Tags: c#

Se eu quiser vender um sistema como autônomo feito na linguagem C#, eu preciso de alguma licença da microsoft? Algum cadastro especial? Algum contrato específico? Possuo alguma limitação?

Comment: Sua pergunta pode não merecer 5 pontos mas ela é bem interessante `+1`

Comment: Aos que fecharam o tópico, dúvidas sobre licenciamento fazem parte do escopo do site ¬¬ http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/792/1658

Comment: @Renan concordo, votando para reabrir. Quem votou para fechar poderia pelo menos clicar no link que você passou e votar contra o tópico. Eu acabei de votar a favor no tópico do meta, acredito que devemos tratar esses assuntos aqui sim.

Comment: Coragem, pois o código é facilmente decompilado!

Answer (score 16):

Depende do tipo de aplicação e dos componentes usados para fazer a aplicação.

### .Net framework

O .Net pode ser instalado em qualquer sistema suportado de graça, então acho que vai depender somente das bibliotecas que tiver usado em sua aplicação. Se você desenvolver tudo, não precisa de nenhuma licença. Quem vai precisar de licença no caso é o usuário, que deve ler e aceitar a licença do framework .Net.

### Mono

Você pode desenvolver para o Mono usando C#, portanto a licença não tem nada que ver com a Microsoft, e sim com o Mono.

### Componentes e bibliotecas

No mais, você vai precisar aceitar as licenças dos componentes que estiver usando. Verifique quais deles são proprietários, e tome as devidas precauções, e obtenha suas licenças. Se forem componentes abertos, basta ter conhecimento do tipo de licença. Algumas requerem que você mencione que está usando a biblioteca/componente em uma tela *"sobre"* do seu sistema, outros requerem que coloque um arquivo junto da distribuição (no caso de aplicações desktop).

### Limitações de distribuição e de monetização

Muitos softwares abertos/livres impõem limitações e deveres para fazer a distribuição dos mesmos. Isso não quer dizer que você não pode vender, não há relação entre vender e distribuir. A maioria dos componentes e bibliotecas de código aberto/livre podem ser vendidas, desde que você respeite os limites quanto à distribuição.

[De uma olhada nesse site, para saber mais sobre as licenças de código aberto](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/)

### Software está em um servidor

Se o software não for desktop, no caso de uma aplicação web, web-service, ou outros do tipo "na-nuvem", então as licenças estarão relacionadas também à instalação de dependências e bibliotecas neste servidor, assim como o próprio Sistema Operacional sendo usado no servidor:

- Sistema Operacional: você deve aceitar os termos de uso do OS
- Banco de dados: você deve aceitar os termos de uso do SGDB
- Outros softwares e serviços do qual o sistema dependa
- Serviço do HOST: você deve aceitar os termos de serviço do HOST em si

Neste caso, verifica-se ainda que nem todos os componentes estão sendo distribuídos. Nestes casos, você deverá verificar somente por limitações de uso e de monetização, mas não de distribuição.